# Does Scanner have its own buffer for reading?

Tags: java, io, buffer

`BufferedReader` and `BufferedInputStream` have their own buffers for reading. Is having buffer the reason why they can read a line at a time?

`Scanner` can read a line at a time too. But it doesn't necessarily work with `BufferedReader` and `BufferedInputStream`. Does it have its own buffer for reading a line at a time?

Thanks.

Comment: Why do you think a class needs a buffer to read a line? A buffer is used to minimize the amount of hardware access and not to read a line or not.

Comment: If not using a buffer, how can it collect the characters into a string?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [Oracle's docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html), in particular, from this line:

> A scanner can read text from any object which implements the Readable interface. If an invocation of the underlying readable's Readable.read(java.nio.CharBuffer) method throws an IOException then the scanner assumes that the end of the input has been reached. The most recent IOException thrown by the underlying readable can be retrieved via the ioException() method.

It appears that `Scanner` doesn't have its own buffer. It uses the buffer from the underlying object (that implements `Readable`), and uses regular expressions for parsing.

Comment: Thanks. "It uses the buffer from the underlying object (that implements Readable)," If the underlying object is not an object of BufferedReader, then `Scannere` will not use any user space buffer?

Comment: Correct. It tokenizes and parses the string directly.